# codeigniter how to set where condition in this query and join to my secound table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

this my query

in this query...i want to join tow table(table1, table2) as the secound query

**first query**

```
 $q = $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('table')
             ->limit($limit, $offset)
             ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);
```

i want on above query such down works but is it posible in above one..when not changing the layout of the query....?

**secound query** this one join works fine i want first query just to do same as secound query

```
 $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('table1');
            $this->db->join('table2', 'table1.t_id', 'table2.id');
            $this->db->limit(9);
            return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: Are you asking if you can change what a query does without changing a query?

Comment: on the first query there is not joing condition so if i want to use join condition how to do that on the first query not secound secound is fine

Comment: Have you tried adding the join portion?

Comment: i want join\(table1, table2) on first query

Comment: Ok, so you have three tables.  one named table, one named table1, and one named table2?  If so, what column in "table" should be used to join to either of the other two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well not sure i catched what you need, but if need to make a simple join use active records as per second query:

```
$q = $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('table')
              ->join('table2', 'table.t_id', 'table2.id')
             ->limit($limit, $offset)
             ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);
```

maybe i didn't catched your trouble but the question is surely not clear